# Integrated Authentication in Jboss Teiid

Tags: jboss, teiid

I want to use Integrated authentication using jdbc connector in Teiid. I have tried to create a connecton to Database using:
1. Create Teiid Model Project-> Source ->Import->JDBC Connection
2. I see a feature called **integrated security** checkbox in **Specify a Driver and Connection profile**.
When i am inserting values there , it is giving me an error. I want to understand if it is supported by Teiid or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is supported as general JBoss EAP feature, but there is no tooling support like in the Teiid Designer as you describe above.

When you create a data source configuration for Oracle in JBoss EAP, define "security-domain",  and then configure a JAAS based security domain that based on Caller Idenity Login Module. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Data_Services/5/html/Data_Services_Administration_Guide/chap-Login_Modules.html

Once you configure that, if Oracle source is being used as one of the sources under Teiid VDB, then the credentials used to log into Teiid will be used to issue queries on Oracle.